# Globbing with python rpm module?

Tags: python, search, rpm, glob

The following code uses the `rpm` module to query the version of an installed package.  What I would like to do is to query a set of packages specified by a glob, for example searching for `"python*"` rather than `"python"`.  Is this possible using the `rpm` module?

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/python
  2 
  3 import rpm
  4 
  5 ts = rpm.TransactionSet()
  6 mi = ts.dbMatch("name", "python")
  7 for i in mi:
  8     print i['name'], i['version']
```

`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import rpm
ts = rpm.TransactionSet()
mi = ts.dbMatch()
mi.pattern('name', rpm.RPMMIRE_GLOB, 'py*' )
for h in mi:
   # Do something with the header...
```